# @Autowired in SpringSecurity Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, autowired

i have a Spring Security configuration like that :

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Override
    ....
```

The ide tell me that Could not autowire dataSource but i have configured the dataSource bean in RootConfiguration class :

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    @EnableJpaRepositories("com.zero.mvc.repository")
    @ComponentScan("com.zero.mvc")
    @Import(SecurityConfig.class)
    public class RootConfiguration {
    ....
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() 
    ...
```

i don't understand why....
thanks!

Comment: i use spring 3.2.4.RELEASE and spring security 3.2.0.RC1

Comment: Does it actually work when you run it or is it just the IDE telling you it cannot be found? Which IDE are you using? If you get an error on startup, can you please provide a full stacktrace?

Comment: Does it happens in the right order? the order of dependency injection?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing an import Annotation like:
@Import(value = { SomeOtherConfig.class })

An example can e.g be found here:
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/beans-spring/spring-3-java-config-import-example/